# Ubuntu SDK and Qt Creator on same machine

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

Can Ubuntu SDK and Qt Creator coexist on the same Ubuntu machine without one affecting the other?

Machine is running Ubuntu 16.04.1 AMD64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can, I also use both Ubuntu SDK and QtCreator, with no problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that both will share their settings. It you do not want that, you will need to move the settings of one by starting it with -settingspath ~/some/place.

Best to put that into a launcher script or the desktop file.